# Squares and Non-squares in Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

I need to find an example of non-squares, non-units $a,b \in \mathbb{Z[i]}$ such that gcd($a,b) =1$ and their product $ab$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z[i]}$.

My approach:

Let $ab = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_n^{e_n}$ for some prime $p_i \in \mathbb{Z[i]}$.  It follows that $e_i$ is even. Furthermore, since
gcd($a,b) =1$, $a$ and $b$ don't share any prime factors. Hence $a = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_k^{e_k}$ and $b = p_{k+1}^{e_{k+1}}p_{k+2}^{e_{k+2}}...p_{n}^{e_{n}}$ for $1 < k \leq n$.

But then I get the conclusion that $a,b$ are squares in $\mathbb{Z[i]}$

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: $4i$ is not a square, nor is $-9i$. And $4i\times-9i=36$? ($\sqrt i=\pm\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$)

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to define squares in the Gaussian integers? for example I know $2i$ is a square since $2i = (x+iy)^2$ but I wouldn't be able to show $4i$ is not a square.

Comment: @awllower Sorry I forgot to tag you

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $4i=(x+yi)^2$. Then $x^2=y^2$ and $2xy=4$. Since $x^2=y^2$, we deduce $x=\pm y$ and $\pm2y^2=4$, and this is clearly not solvable in integers.

The same argument shows that $-9i$ is not a square in $\mathbb Z[i]$. But $4i\times-9i=36$.

The problem with your argument is that you forgot about units: $a$ can be written as $u\times p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_k^{e_k}$ and $b=u^{-1}\times p_{k+1}^{e_{k+1}}p_{k+2}^{e_{k+2}}...p_{n}^{e_{n}}$. Now $u$ can be a non-square, and so $a$ can be a non-square.

---

Hope this helps.